# CSP allow specific: data:font/woff;base64,"someBase64encoded font", WITHOUT using csp: font-src 'self' data:

Tags: css, fonts, base64, content-security-policy

Have a few embed base64 fonts in some css files, but CSP blocks these:
something like `url("data:font/woff;base64,d09GRk9UVE...);`

Current CSP = "base-uri 'self'; connect-src 'self'; default-src 'none'; font-src 'self'; form-action 'self'; frame-ancestors 'none'; frame-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; style-src 'self';"

W3 and MDN say I could add a hash, but this doesn't seem to work either

tried `sha256`,`sha384`,`sha512`

Answer (score 43):

Add `data:`to font-source, e.g.

```
font-src 'self' data:;
```

Comment: Isn't this specifically what OP doesn't want to use?

Comment: This can also open a security threat, see the docs for CSP font-src directive

Comment: This works for me using the Phoenix 1.6.10. I was trying a lot of hours how to fix this.
Thank you @solitud

Comment: But I have problems when I try to import the google fonts I receive this complain:
`
Refused to load the stylesheet 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100&display=swap' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'". Note that 'style-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.`